# XDebug for PHP 4.3.9

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

My server is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 8).
I need to debug an old PHP project. 
Which XDebug version supports PHP 4.3.9 (Zend Engine 1.3.0) ?
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such version.

PHP is only [supported up from version 7.3](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), and supported versions of Xdebug are 2.9 (for [PHP 7.2 and higher](https://xdebug.org/docs/compat)). PHP 4.3 has not been supported for at least 12 years, and if you're still stuck on it, then your site is full of security holes. Not even RedHat supports this old version any more.

All Xdebug releases are at https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.org/tree/master/html/files, and I believe the latest that works with PHP 4.3, is Xdebug 2.0.5,  but I have no means of testing that any more.

Comment: Thanks Derick. Does XDebug support only PHP from version 4.4? Like Xdebug 2.0.0.

Comment: Updated my answer with the potentially last version that works with 4.3

Answer (score 1):

What Derick said, but if you are adamant on needing/doing that, [use the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090315045032/http://xdebug.org/download.php) and download [version 1.3.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20090315045032/http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-1.3.2.tgz) or [version 1.3.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20090315045032/http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-1.3.1.tgz). I actually don't know if these versions support 4.3, but you seem desperate, so it's your best bet.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I'll give it a try. And yes, I'm desperate.